# How to make link not clickable when a user on that link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I do have menu in a footer, it's just a ul. That ul contains hrefs to other website pages. Is there anyway to check if a user on one of this pages and make that link not clickable at all? I do know that i need to apply style:
`user_on_it{ pointer-events: none; }` 
But dont know how to make a check

I tired ::before ::after things but didnt maange to combine in a working code

Comment: In your attempt, what specifically doesn't work as expected or where specifically are you stuck?  Are you asking how to read the current URL in JavaScript?  How to apply a CSS class to an element in JavaScript?  Something else?  Can you demonstrate the attempt and indicate what isn't working?

Comment: To achieve this, you need to check the current URL of the page and compare it with the URL of the link in your footer. If they match, you can disable the link using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do this with Javascript with some comments to explain the code:

```
// get current URL
var currentPageUrl = window.location.href;

// loop through each link (you can query links with your classes, it's just an example)
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(link) {
  // get the link's URL
  var linkHref = link.getAttribute('href');
  
  // compare the current URL and link's URL
  if (currentPageUrl === linkHref) {
    // add the CSS class to disable link
    link.classList.add('user_on_it');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you need to check the current URL of the page and compare it with the URL of the link in your footer. If they match, you can disable the link using CSS.

```js
const currentUrl = window.location.href;

const footerLinks = document.querySelectorAll('footer ul li a');

footerLinks.forEach(link => {
  if (link.href === currentUrl) {
    link.classList.add('user_on_it');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current page URL using `window.location.href` and assign a disabled class to the link you want.

For example, here I am checking if the current page URL includes the `stack overflow` keyword, then disable the `Google` link.

```js
const gLink = document.getElementById('google');
!gLink.classList.contains('disabled') && window.location.href.includes("stack") ? gLink.classList.add('disabled') : gLink.classList.remove('disabled')
```

```css
a.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="google">Google Link</a>
<a href="#" id="so">SO Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can check the element `href` and compare it with `window.location.href`
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (window.location.href === e.currentTarget.href) e.preventDefault();
    console.log('A link was clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="/new-link">Not current link</a>
<a href="/js">Current Link </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

to make the check you would need to get the location of the user by using:

```
   const url = window.location.href;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).